# Is kubernetes api library targeted for windows OS platform?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl

We would like to have GoLang tool(running on windows) that use `client-go` library(https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go).

Plan is to use this tool instead of `kubectl`.

---

Before going for development,

Does `client-go` library allow the tool to consume kubeconfig from windows machine and talk to kubernetes clusters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does client-go library allow the tool to consume kubeconfig from windows machine and talk to kubernetes clusters?

Yes, and you can pass the custom path of the kubeconfig as well.

by default its looking into

```
KUBE_CONFIG_DEFAULT_LOCATION = os.environ.get('KUBECONFIG', '~/.kube/config')
```

so you can pass the env `export KUBECONFIG=your_custom_path`

Here is the function

```
def load_kube_config(config_file=None, context=None,
                     client_configuration=None,
                     persist_config=True):
    """Loads authentication and cluster information from kube-config file
    and stores them in kubernetes.client.configuration.

    :param config_file: Name of the kube-config file.
    :param context: set the active context. If is set to None, current_context
        from config file will be used.
    :param client_configuration: The kubernetes.client.Configuration to
        set configs to.
    :param persist_config: If True, config file will be updated when changed
        (e.g GCP token refresh).
    """
```

[go-client-install](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/INSTALL.md)

Comment: We are using `kubectl oidc login` and the config file has OIDC authentication. Is `client-go` library a right fit for talking to kubernetes clusters?

Comment: Do I need to use this package? https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/f6ce18ae578c8cca64d14ab9687824d9e1305a67/plugin/pkg/client/auth/oidc/oidc.go

Comment: the `client-go` support oidc and the link you have mentioned is from the same package

Comment: if you are able to run `kubectl whatever` then the `client-go` should be able to perform the operation, the config file is used for authentication and client-go relay on the config file.